# Print column names only once in shell script

Tags: mysql, shell

Here is my shell script and It is working fine without any errors. But i want to get output differently.

### Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
DB_USER='root'
DB_PASSWD='123456'
DB_NAME='job'
Table_Name='status_table'
#sql=select job_name, date,status from $DB_NAME.$Table_Name where job_name='$f1' and date=CURDATE()
file="/root/jobs.txt"
while read -r f1
do
    mysql -N -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWD  <<EOF
select job_name, date,status from $DB_NAME.$Table_Name where job_name='$f1' and date=CURDATE()

EOF
done <"$file"
```

### Source Table:

```
mysql> select * from job.status_table
+---------+----------+------------+-----------+
| Job_id  | Job Name |     date   |   status  |
+---------+----------+--------+---------------+
|   111   |    AA    | 2016-12-01 | completed |
|   112   |    BB    | 2016-12-01 | completed |
|   113   |    CC    | 2016-12-02 | completed |
|   112   |    BB    | 2016-12-01 | completed |
|   114   |    DD    | 2016-12-02 | completed |
|   201   |    X     | 2016-12-03 | completed |
|   202   |    y     | 2016-12-04 | completed |
|   203   |    z     | 2016-12-03 | completed |
|   111   |    A     | 2016-12-04 | completed |
+---------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

### Input text file

```
[rteja@server0 ~]# more jobs.txt
AA
BB
CC
DD
X
Y
Z
A
ABC
XYZ
```

### Output - Supressed coumn names

```
(mysql -N -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWD  <<EOF)
[rteja@server0 ~]# ./script.sh
  AA       2016-12-01   completed
  BB       2016-12-01   completed
```

### Output - without Suppressed column names, output printing the columns names for every loop iteration.

```
(mysql -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWD  <<EOF)

    [rteja@server0 ~]# ./script.sh
    job_name      date        status
      AA       2016-12-01   completed
    job_name      date        status
      BB       2016-12-01   completed
```

**Challenges:**

**1.** Want to print column names only once in output and the result i want to store in CSV file.

**2.** I don't want to expose password & username in code to everyone. Is there way to hide like i heard we can create environmental variables and call it in the script. And we can set the permissions for the environmental variable file to prevent everyone to access it, and only our should be able to access it.

Comment: The shell commands (generally speaking) aren't for production other than some maintenance tasks. You should be using some other language to perform tasks like this, like PHP, Python, node.js, etc. That way your code (and sensitive information) isn't exposed to users.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than executing a select query multiple times you can run a single query as:

```
job_name in ('AA','BB','CC'...)
```

To do that first read complete file in an array using `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t arr < jobs.txt
```

Then format the array values into a list of values suited for `IN` operator:

```
printf -v cols "'%s'," "${arr[@]}"
cols="(${cols%,})"
```

Display your values:

```
echo "$cols"
('AA','BB','CC','DD','X','Y','Z','A','ABC','XYZ')
```

Finally run your SQL query as:

```
mysql -N -u$DB_USER -p$DB_PASSWD <<EOF
select job_name, date,status from $DB_NAME.$Table_Name
where job_name IN "$cols" and date=CURDATE();
EOF
```

To **securely connecting to MySQL** [use login-paths (`.mylogin.cnf`)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysql-utils-intro-connspec-mylogin.cnf.html)

As per MySQL manual:

> The best way to specify server connection information is with your `.mylogin.cnf` file. Not only is this file encrypted, but any logging of the utility execution does not expose the connection information.